# Apache not loading right DocumentRoot

Tags: macos, apache

Have got myself stuck and can't find where the problem is.

Here is what I have:
OS X El Capitan

```
$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
```

My /etc/hosts files:

```
127.0.0.1    first.loc  
127.0.0.1    second.loc
```

/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/projects/first"
    ServerName first.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/projects/second"
    ServerName second.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

I have put 3 index.html files with their directories as the only text in them:

```
/Users/me/projects/index.html (1)  
/Users/me/projects/first/index.html (2)  
/Users/me/projects/second/index.html (3)
```

When I go to first.loc or second.loc it loads the projects/index.html.

When I go to first.loc/first it loads the second index.html, when I go to first.loc/second it loads the 3rd.

Why are the DocumentRoots not being processed correctly?

Solved and answered below: Web Sharing panel was stopping Apache being restarted fully so it wasn't actually reloading the config files. Turning that off and manually starting/stopping/restarting has resolved.

Comment: perhaps there is another (default/catchall) vhost configured?

Comment: Not one that I'm aware of - I certainly haven't made one and I'm not aware of there being any other vhost.conf files apart from that particular one. I removed all the default content from it so what is above is all that's in it.

Comment: `apachectl -S` should list them, please do check

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems the problem has 'fixed' itself. The issue was not with Apache but with `sudo apachectl restart` not working properly.

I previously installed a Web Sharing panel to try out which was set to 'On'. With that set, it seems to stop all the apache processes from stopping so it never truly stops and restarts with the updated config files.

Have removed the silly panel and now starting and stopping manually and it's all working as it should!